# NestJS API calls and reading response data within the API

Tags: node.js, express, axios, nestjs, endpoint

I'm building a NestJS api and need to make a call to an outside API and parse the responding data. This is a healthCheck to see if another API is up and running. Here is the basic call:

```
    @Get('healthCheck')
    public async healthCheck(
        @Req() req: Request,
        @Res() res: Response,
    )
    {
        const obj = this.test(req);
        console.log(obj)
    }

    test(req) {
        const testingURL = 'https://google.com';
        return this.http.get(testingURL).pipe(
            map((obj: AxiosResponse) => { return obj.data } ),
            tap(console.log)
        );
    }
```

I've worked extensively with angular in the past and doing any sort of ".toPromise()" or "subscribe()" on the returned data causes a "Converting circular structure to JSON".

Currently the "console.log(obj)" in the first section is printing out an observable object that cannot be parsed:

```
Observable {
  source: Observable {
    source: Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] },
    operator: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Any advice or helpful hints would be helpful. Most other posts that discuss this issue say that simple mapping the response or adding a promise fixes the issue, but it does not explain further on how to parse that observable once it's been fetched.

Edit: solution posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576186/jay-mcdoniel for help on this and this project reference https://github.com/jmcdo29/heart-watch/blob/feat/nest-commander/src/character-reader/character-reader.api.service.ts

Here was my working solution:

```
  @Get('healthCheck')
  public async healthCheck() {
    const obj = await this.getEndpoint('https://google.com');
    console.log(obj);
  }

  private getEndpoint(url): Promise<any> {
    return lastValueFrom(
      this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
        map((res) => {
          return res.data;
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This should parse any get (or post) endpoint, as long as parameters/auth isn't required, and return the observable parsed into a promise in nestjs using axios.

Edit: as Jay suggested, lastValueFrom used instead of depricated toPromise()

Comment: Just note that `toPromise` is deprecated and will not be used in RxJS v8. Use `lastValueFrom(observable)` for RxJS v7 and on

Answer (score 1):

You should inject `HttpService` from `HttpModule` (`@nestjs/axios`) and get the axios reference like this `this.httpService.axiosRef.get(...)`

See official documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. unless you have a reason, don't inject `@Res()` to the route handler, just return your data and let Nest handle it rather than having to call `res.send()`. If you need access to response headers or setting cookies, use `@Res({ passthrough: true })`
2. You can return an observable in Nest directly and Nest will handle reading the data and sending it back for you.
3. if you need to read a value inside the observable, you can use the `tap` operator from RxJS and `pipe(tap(console.log))` to read the data

---

EDIT 10/15/2021

Now that I've also read that you're wanting to use this data in another API call, you have two options:

1. use `lastValueFrom` to convert the RxJS Observable into a `Promise` so that it can be `await`ed. Straightforward and easy to work with
2. use operators like `mergeMap` or `switchMap` and chain together your Observables, still returning a single observable in the end. RxJS is like really powerful callbacks with extra options on top, but they can also get complex so this option usually requires a bit more nuance and dedication to ensure the operators are chained correctly.

Comment: Agreed on points 1/2. Specifically I need to be able to parse the data within the API itself and will be returning something like "res.write('Connection Made)" (hence why I'm including the response as a param - I just haven't done that part yet). For 3, when I add the tap pipe it logs the following: "Observable {
  source: Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}" (i.e. an observable object) which I cannot parse / read, how do I parse this observable object? Hopefully that makes sense, thanks for the help!

Comment: You've added that `tap` after the `map` operator, right? Basically, you shouldn't need to ever do `console.log(observableObject)`, because it won't return anything meaningful

Comment: I updated the code snippet / description. It returns the same observable object type.

Comment: You're still logging the observable object in you `healthCheck` code. That method just needs to return the observable, just like `test` does. Nest will use `lastValueFrom` under the hood to get the data out of it

Comment: I may not have made the question clear enough. I need the data from this API call for another API call (both calls are outside of this system). I don't have access to the database directly, hence why I need to make an API call. In other words I need the observable data parsed within the `healthCheck` method itself so I can call another function with that data as a parameter.

Comment: What about chaining rxjs operators with things like `mergeMap` and `switchMap`?

Comment: Tried that and no luck. I'm starting to think it might be an issue with the HTTPService from 'nestjs/axios'. The docs don't give much information and don't give a good example: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module#getting-started

Comment: Also, the console.log in the map doesn't print anything out. That's why I'm thinking something else is going on..

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/retryable-http-nestjs) shows some usage of the `HttpService` (back from v7, but the API is the same in v8, just change the package name), and [this repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay) has a lot of RxJS usage in it (`apps/api/src`). It's also back on Nest v7, but it's an Open Source personal project of mine that may help with RxJS usage for you. Lots of chained operations all over the place

Comment: Both of these applications are doing the same thing of fetching and returning the observable object back to the UI. Neither of them are making an endpoint call within the API and parsing that response within the API itself.

Comment: The tabletop companion repo is great though, I will definitely be taking a further look later :)

Comment: [This one (different repo) does](https://github.com/jmcdo29/heart-watch/blob/feat/nest-commander/src/character-reader/character-reader.api.service.ts). It recursively calls an API based on the data in the response of the first API call, until there's no more paginated data

Comment: Thanks for the help!